# Discover if any Dialog is being open?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a BaseActivity that opens Dialogs on it's code, but I can't change this class code, so I extended it, on my subclass, how to know when a Dialog is being open?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to override `onCreateDialog()`.  This passes a reference ID that is used when the Activity calls `showDialog(id)`.  If you just need to know if any `Dialog` is going to be shown, then I suppose you could call the super which will return the dialog that will be shown.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
   Dialog dialogToBeShown = super.onCreateDialog(id);
   if(dialogToBeShown != null){
      ***Do whatever you have to with the dialog***
   }
   return dialogToBeShown;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This will only work the first time the Dialog is first created.   You can do something similar with `onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args)` which is always called when a dialog is opening.

Answer (score 0):

Dialog has an isShowing() method that should return if the dialog is currently visible. So you can use that to see if a dialog is showing and hide it with dismissDialog(). You just have to keep a reference to the Dialogs you create in onCreateDialog().

Comment: I don't have any references to the Dialog, I need to intercept it's creation to keep one.